# Ruby regex gsub any other characters except + on start (phone number)

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub

I am looking to remedy the following formats or invalid formats to a working phone number:

```
1 (639)-234-2323 => 6392342323
2 (042)-982-2234 => 0429822234
3 0974829-928  => 0974829928
4 +83246-983-34 => +832459834
5 +836(737)-898+78 => +83673789878
```

I am able to use this code and I can get my results right if a certain 1-4 are given, but if `5`, I am really going nuts.

```
row[1] = row[1].gsub('(','').gsub(')','').gsub('-','').gsub(' ','')
```

This sample is used in an import file. So you can't expect a prompt to a user.

I am also open to possibly importing record with invalid format, but should just be formatted into an accepted phone number (given parentheses inside anywhere or any `+` signs anywhere).

**EDIT** I want to have a solution to my `5` given example. Since I can't remove `+` signs anywhere without removing the first one.

**EDIT 2** I asked again in the comment section that I need to include such phone format:

```
6 (+65)92349577 => +6592348577
```

@WiktorStribiżew suggested the following regex: `s.gsub(/\A\(?(\+)|\D+/, '\1')` from his original answer (the accepted one)

Comment: Use `s.gsub(/\A(\+)|\D+/, '\1')`

Comment: Sorry, question was updated.. I want to have a solution to my `5` given example. Since I can't remove `+` signs anywhere without removing the first one.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Brilliant answer.. Could you atleast post an answer so I can accept yours? Thank you for a quick reply.

Comment: @DanielChristiany sorry for vague question. I was supposed to cut my question before `row[1] = row[1].gsub('(','').gsub(')','').gsub('-','').gsub(' ','')`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew What if I want to add new search `(+` from (+65)92349577 and replace it by `'\1'`, Output should be like: +6592348577 .. how would that be possible?  i tried `^(\+)|^(\(\+)|[^\d\n]` on your regex demo but cannot replace it.

Comment: If you want to protect a `(` before the initial `+` try `s.gsub(/\A(\(?\+)|\D+/, '\1')`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you for responding.. (+65)92349577 => +6592348577 this is what I want to achieve, I want get only the `+` sign and remove the `(` to get a working phone number. But it should be on the beginning.

Comment: Then move the parenthesis outside the group - `s.gsub(/\A\(?(\+)|\D+/, '\1')`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew works like charm! I really need to eat a lot to know more about regex! Thank you so much! I'll update the question to include this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to capture the first `+` and just match all other non-digit symbols:

```
s.gsub(/\A(\+)|\D+/, '\1')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MxT8g9/1)

**Pattern details**:

- `\A(\+)` - a `+` (that is captured into a capturing group #1 since it is wrapped with capturing parentheses) at the beginning of the string (`\A`)
- `|` - or
- `\D+` -  one or more characters other than a digit.

The `\1` in the replacement is a backreference to the contents stored in capturing group #1, it restores the initial `+` in the replacement result

Comment: Why are the parens are the `+` sign required?

Comment: @akuhn: The first alternative branch value must be kept in the final result. To be able to put this text back into the replacement result, the value should be stored in some memory slot that is created with a capturing group. The `(...)` create the capture, and thus the `+` that is at the string start can be kept. We match and *capture* what we need to keep, and just match what we need to remove.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Woah! Excellent answer with explanation. Thank you! I am still learning this regex thing, and I just have to deal with a current task needs to be done. Great! Thank you!

Comment: Oh, and because the other alternative has no capture it gets replaced by nothing. Too smart, hahaha!

Comment: @akuhn: Yes, it is possible as the backreference value is set to an empty string if the capturing group is not participating in the match. It is not the case in Python `re` before Version 3.5, but has been working well in Onigmo and many other regex engines.